# Can a warlock use one of their Thirsting Blade attacks to grapple or shove?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, grapple

As a Warlock with the Thirsting Blade Invocation, can I replace one of the Attacks with my pact weapon with a Grapple/Shove?

The only wording difference between Thirsting Blade and Extra attack is: "with your pact weapon"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## No, you may not replace one of the attacks with a grapple

Thirsting Blade states:

> **Thirsting Blade, PHB 111**
>
> You can attack **with your pact weapon** twice, instead of once, whenever you take the Attack action on your turn.

If you are using any other weapon other than your pact weapon, you may not attack twice. A grapple is a special melee attack which does not use a weapon, making it mutually exclusive with Thirsting Blade.

Comment: But grapple says "If you’re able to make multiple attacks with the
Attack action, this attack replaces one of them." And I am able to make multiple attacks with the attack action right?

Comment: @Lichtbringer You are able to make multiple attacks with the Attack action if and only if you use your pact weapon. Otherwise, you cannot make multiple attacks with the Attack action. If you are using your pact weapon to attack, you are not grappling.

Comment: If you first grapple, haven't you used the attack action, by RAW? And therefore, aren't you able to attack with your pact weapon?

Answer (score -3):

The power clearly states that you can make another attack with your boon weapon.  It does not say you can grapple.  Also it is not am extra attack.  So the Invocation is not equal to the fighters extra attack ability.

How ever if you were a 5th level Warlock and a 5th level fighter, you could attack 6 times in one turn.

Comment: Can you state the specific text for the 6 attacks? The Invocation says that whenever you use the Attack (big "A") Action you attack (small "a") twice with your pact weapon and Extra Attack states that whenever you use the Attack Action you can attack twice. The two seem mutually exclusive to me, except that the invocation forces you to use your pact weapon, whereas the Extra Attack does not.

Answer (score -5):

you can technically use a weapon to grapple and shove people in real life,  swords and quarter staffs can be used as grappling bars for hooking, leverage and joint breaking.

So I don't see any problem with grappling or shoving, in replace of an attack as long as you shove/grapple with your pact weapon.

Comment: The question is asking about how specific rules/mechanics within the game interact. Unfortunately basing an answer off what's possible in real life doesn't really apply to the situation.

Comment: While I agree with you Garret (see Jackie Chan for many examples of weapon grappling), 5e requires a free hand to perform a grapple. This means the weapon is explicitly not being used to perform a grapple.